# R define a multidimensional object to behave like a vector

Tags: r, oop, object, r-s4

I would like to define a slightly more general version of a complex number in R. This should be a vector that has more than one component, accessible in a similar manner to using Re() and Im() for complex numbers. Is there a way to do this using S3/S4 classes?

I have read through the [OO field guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) among other resources, but most solutions seem focused around the use of lists as fundamental building objects. However, I need vectors for use in data.frames and matrices. I was hoping to use complex numbers as a template, but they seem to be implemented largely in C. At this point, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: To quote the field guide: _"Base types are not really an object system because only the R core team can create new types"_. So I guess no?

Comment: Yes, I caught that line. It would be unfortunate if that would be the only way of doing this. I guess I'm asking if there is a way to accomplish something similar using S3/S4.

Comment: @ssokolen Do you mean that you need a vector because you can't have columns of lists in data.frames? Because you can. But maybe I misunderstand your desire for a non-listy implementation...

Comment: @TaylorH 
 
Ideally, I'd like to reproduce many of the things that the complex type does, i.e., the ability to form matrices as well as data.frames, play nicely with mathematical functions that take vector inputs, etc... It seemed like this would be quite a complex undertaking using a list framework, but perhaps I'm missing something.